# C# Modifying Identity or Add a Claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor, claims-based-identity

Application is Blazor Server .NET Core 5.0

I am using .NET Core's Identity system and I am running into a problem. I want to have the person's first name stored with the Identity so I can call on it easily.

Currently I have a class overriding the base identity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base() { }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My startup.cs has:

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
            }
        )
```

In my mind that should force the program's intellisense to understand ApplicationUser is the default class when looking for identity.

However, when I try to call:

```
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;
```

It only returns "IdentityUser" data rather than my custom ApplicationUser class.

Is there something I am missing with what AuthenticationStateProvider is returning or a type casting I am missing?

Also, if this is completely incorrect, should I do this with Claims? If so, I cannot find a concrete way to effectively use claims with Blazor Server.

Comment: WebAssembly or Server-side blazor?

Comment: @Brian, it is Server-side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Execute in the Package Manager Console:

1. add-migration CreateAppUser
2. update-database

Insert values to the FirstName and LastName created in the Users table

Create a class named: ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation

### ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation.cs

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication3.Data;
using WebApplication3.Models;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

 public class ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var identity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsAuthenticated);
            if (identity == null) return principal;

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
            if (user == null) return principal;

            // Add or replace identity.Claims.

          
             if (!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName))
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
       
        }
        if (!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname))
        {
          identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName));
        }

            return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        }
    }
```

### Startup.ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, 
           ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation>();
```

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthState
@using System.Security
@using System.Security.Claims

@foreach(var c in user.Claims)
{
    <div>@c.Type:  @c.Value</div>
}
@code
    {

    private ClaimsPrincipal user;

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var x = await AuthState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        user =  x.User;
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    }
```

Note: You should alter the IdentityUser name to ApplicationUser in
the Startup class, LogOut.cshtml file, _LoginPartial.cshtml file and
in the definition of the ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have something to help read about this topic?  Microsoft documentation is great on implementation on Authorization under Claims but not so much of an explanation on Claims and how their associated classes and interfaces work.

Comment: No, sorry, I did not search any source in order to solve your question. But I did just now...I've searched "IClaimsTransformation blazor" and got a single irrelevant result. Of course if you Google up only the "IClaimsTransformation" term you'll get some results from blogs telling you about this interface and how you can use it in Asp.Net Core. I could answer your question because I've learned a great deal about authentication and authorization, Identity providers, and such like. I'd advise you to go to the web site of chris sainty, and learn from his articles this field.

Comment: You may also read the docs, try to implement what they do ( usually the offer partial solutions) and then come here and post your questions. I've first learned about the existence of Blazor from the web site of Chris Sainty. I then came here and started to answer question on a daily basis, which proved to be the best way to learn Blazor.

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down for me! Im fairly new to stack overflow and that's really appreciated when someone helps out with the mannerisms of the site. I have marked it. I will check that guy out. I promise I was in the documentation for about 3 hours bashing my head. I love microsoft's documentation they have great examples but not for anything imo. But I'll supplement with the individual you said to look into. Again thank you for the help!

Comment: @cobb208, I've introduced some changes in my code... Make sure you copy the last version.

Comment: @enet I have tried this in Blazor server. But there is one problem . Claims get updated only after I manually refresh the Browser..  Could you please help me solve this issue.

Comment: @enet Can I inject dependencies into ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation ?

Comment: What if I need to bring claim values from somewhere else? For eg: some service needs to be called to get let's say `EmployeeId`. How can I add that as claims during login? Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75377386/8644294

Comment: I have used the implementation using ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation and then registration in default DI container and it worked a treat. thnx 4 sharing this approach @enet.